# Pulling Columns from Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

[image: Example]

[ExampleData](http://www.filedropper.com/example_2)

I'm trying to pull from a total of 6 columns from an excel worksheet. I'm using a modified script from another post on stack, it looks like this.

```html
$strPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\EXEL\fj.xls"
$AssetInv = "C:\Users\User\Documents\EXEL\fj.txt"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Daily Price Quote - Better Of -")
$intRowMax =  ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
#$StartRow = 2                       
#$site = 1                         
#$state = 3                     
#$retailprice = 18              
#$yourprice = 20
#$SavingsTotal = 21

Write "`Site City      State      retailprice     yourprice    savingstotal" | Out-File $AssetInv
Write "--------------- ------------------- -------------------- -----------------------------" | 
      Out-FIle $AssetInv -Append

Write-Host "Processing: " $intRowMax "rows"

for ($intRow = 7 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++) {
     $site = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 10).value2
     $city = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 2).value2
     $state = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 3).value2
     $retailprice = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 18).value2
     $yourprice = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 20).value2
$SavingsTotal = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow, 21).value2


     if (($site -ge 1 ))  {
         "{0, -15} {1, -30} {2, -25} {3, -25}" -f $site, $city, $state, $retailprice, $yourprice, $Savingstotal | 
          Out-File $AssetInv -Append
     }
 }

$objexcel.quit()
```

Currently I am pulling no data, earlier I had it working for a maximum of 3 records. Any insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are doing this the hard way. Please update your question with sample data (are there headers in the excel file?), and what columns you want to extract. Pretty sure I can make this simpler for you.

Comment: updated for you, thanks for the reply. See Pic at the top of the post.

Comment: We still need sample data. Asking us to recreate it from a picture is not the most friendly approach

Comment: Meh, I don't really need sample data for this. I'll get an answer posted shortly. This should be pretty simple.

Comment: In any case Ive added sample data, sorry for any confusion. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, we'll start with your code to get the worksheet we want. Then we'll select the UsedRange to get the range of cells that have data. Then we'll run that through a ForEach loop, skipping the first 5 rows since they have garbage/header info. For each row we'll make a new object, with properties set to the associated cell (kind of like what you do with all your variables). All of those objects will be collected in an array, which we output to a CSV file. If you don't like the CSV, you could pipe it to Format-Table, and pipe that to Out-File (might have to pipe to out-string, then out-file... it's not something I do often).

```
$strPath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\EXEL\fj.xls"
$AssetInv = "C:\Users\User\Documents\EXEL\fj.txt"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Daily Price Quote - Better Of -")

$UsedRange = $worksheet.usedrange

$Data = ForEach($Row in ($UsedRange.Rows|Select -skip 5)){
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Site' = $Row.Cells.Item(1).Value2
        'City' = $Row.Cells.Item(2).Value2
        'State' = $Row.Cells.Item(3).Value2
        'Retail Price' = $Row.Cells.Item(18).Value2
        'Your Price' = $Row.Cells.Item(20).Value2
        'Total Savings' = $Row.Cells.Item(21).Value2
    }
}

$Data | Where{[int]::Parse($_.Site) -ge 1} | Select Site,City,State,'Retail Price','Your Price','Total Savings' | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $AssetInv

$objExcel.quit()
```

The plus side is that you also are left with $Data which is all the data you want to be able to use in case you need to do anything else with it (look for items that you save over X%, or items that cost less than $5 or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your post, upon trying your script I get no output or completion.  (this is in the ISE)

Comment: I found 2 issues that I fixed in my code. One was that I skipped one too many lines, The other is that you were referencing column 10 for the Site, when it should be column 1. I fixed that. Then updated the Where statement so that it parses the Site property from a string to a number for the -ge comparison. Tested with your example file and it worked OK for me at this point.

Comment: If this accurately answers your question please mark the answer as accepted so that others do not spend time trying to answer it, and so that future users can review the answer for their own use if they have a similar issue.

Comment: Okay after a day of troubleshooting your code it seems to be working as is, for whatever reason it is taking a long time to run, but it DOES run and produce the desired effect. It had seemed to work intermittently but I'm getting to run well now. Thank you.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I have just implemented this for my spreadsheet and have found that it is the "Select -skip 5" part that is making it take absolutely ages.  With that select in the script, it takes about 10 minutes to run, but without it, it takes less than a minute.

Comment: @hshah I'm not sure how the `ForEach` call works that. It may be re-evaluating that array `($UsedRange.Rows|Select -Skip 5)`, on each iteration. You may want to declare that first, and capture it in its own variable, then reference that variable at that point.