# Powershell script to read column 2 data from .xlsx file

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to get of 2 columns of a .xlsx file. Can anyone help me here.

My .xlsx file looks like this:

```
ProductName         ProductCode
----------------------------------------------------------
Java 7 Update 75    {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
Java 8 Update 25    {26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
```

I want output which will write only product codes line by line

```
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789012}
{26374892-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-902341562789}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [ImportExcel Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) by Doug Finke to import the spreadsheet into a PowerShell object to operate on:

```
Install-Module importexcel
Import-Excel C:\path\to\spreadsheet.xlsx | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductCode
```

Comment: Any other way other than ImportExcel Module ?

Comment: @Naveen It doesn't get easier as using `Import-Excel` - what about using google or the above search box (before asking a question)? Possible Duplicate of [pulling-columns-from-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727113/pulling-columns-from-excel)